# h:dataTable does not show any records

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, cdi

I`m trying to use CDI and JSF to get a list of all books in database formatted as dataTable and printed in web page, but instead of this I get empty page. I also tried to use JSF selectOneMenu instead of dataTable but result is the same.

Here`s the code of page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <head>
        <title>Publish a book</title>
    </head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:dataTable value="#{pub.allBooks}" var="c">
                <h:column>#{c.title}</h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </ui:define>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.List;

@Model
@ManagedBean("pub")
public class PublishABookController {

    @Inject
    PublishABook publishABook;

    @Inject
    FacesContext facesContext;

    @Produces
    @Named
    List<Book> allBooks;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initBooks(){
        allBooks = publishABook.getAllBooks();
    }
}
```

Service

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Stateless
public class PublishABookImpl implements PublishABook {

    @Inject
    private PublisherDAO publisherDAO;

    @Inject
    private BookDAO bookDAO;

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Override
    public void publishABook(Publisher publisher, Book book) {
            bookDAO.save(book);
            publisher.getPublishedBooks().add(book);
            publisherDAO.update(publisher);
            logger.info("Book created");
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        return bookDAO.list();
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you debug? Why are you using `#{pub.allBooks}` while you make 'allBooks' available via a producer? Do you get any errors running you application in jsf development mode? And if it fails with another component to, why did you tag it  'datatable'? The cause is most likely somewere else. Tried a plain `ui:repeat`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `<ui:define name="content"></define>` element from the page.

`ui:define` is commonly used for JSF pages templating, but in your context it just prevents rendering content of the page.